# android baseadapter did not correctly

Tags: android, android-listview, arraylist, baseadapter

i have baseadapter and i try to adapter some values in listview.i loged strings witch i adaptered in baseadapter and i have diliver different result.in BaseAdapter Class also logend this texts and this both text are different
this is a my Main Java source

```
public class MoviesRolls extends Fragment {

public final static String TAG = MoviesRolls.class.getSimpleName();

private ListView holllistview;
private HollAdapters adapter;
public static ArrayList<CinemaInfoModel> cinemaInfoArray;
public static CinemaInfoModel timeInfo;


public static MoviesRolls newInstance() {
return new MoviesRolls();}


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater
        .inflate(R.layout.moviesholls, container, false);

holllistview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.holllistview);

holllistview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.holllistview);



ServerItems mainItem = MainmoviesList.arrayOfList
        .get(MainmoviesList.mPosition);

ArrayList<CinemaModel> cinemas = mainItem.getCinema();
ArrayList<CinemaInfoModel> infos = new ArrayList<CinemaInfoModel>();
for (int i = 0; i < cinemas.size(); i++) {
    CinemaModel cinema = cinemas.get(i);
    cinemaInfoArray = cinema.getCinemTimeInfo();
    for (int j = 0; j < cinemaInfoArray.size(); j++) {
        timeInfo = cinemaInfoArray.get(j);

        Log.wtf("logcat start time",
                timeInfo.getTimeformat().get(j));
        Log.wtf("log cat end time",
                timeInfo.getEndTimeFormat().get(
                        j));

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date _d;
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat new_df = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM");
            _d = df.parse(timeInfo.getTimeformat().get(
                    j));
            Date _d1 = df.parse(timeInfo.getEndTimeFormat().get(
                   j));
            String datetimeis = getDateDiffString(_d1, _d);
            int differentdays = Integer.parseInt(datetimeis);
            Log.e("Different is ", String.valueOf(differentdays));
            for (int k = 0; k < differentdays; k++) {

                String datetimeformat = dateFormatter(timeInfo
                        .getTimeformat().get(j));

                Date datetime = new_df.parse(datetimeformat);

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(datetime);
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, k);

                datetime = cal.getTime();

                String ttime = new_df.format(datetime);
                timeInfo.setStartTimePeriod(ttime);
                System.out.println(ttime);
            infos.add(timeInfo);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    adapter = new HollAdapters(getActivity(), infos);
    holllistview.setAdapter(adapter);

}
return rootView;
}

   public String getDateDiffString(Date dateOne, Date dateTwo) {
   long timeOne = dateOne.getTime();
   long timeTwo = dateTwo.getTime();
   long oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
   long delta = (timeTwo - timeOne) / oneDay;

   if (delta > 0) {

    for (int i = 0; i < delta; i++) {

    }
    return String.valueOf(delta);
} else {
    delta *= -1;
    return String.valueOf(delta);
    }
  }


public static String dateFormatter(String inputDate) {

String inputFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
String outputFormat = "d MMM";

Date parsed = null;
String outputDate = "";
try {
    SimpleDateFormat df_input = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat,
            new Locale("en", "US"));
    SimpleDateFormat df_output = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat,
            new Locale("en", "US"));

    parsed = df_input.parse(inputDate);
    outputDate = df_output.format(parsed);

    // Log.wtf("outputDate", outputDate);
} catch (Exception e) {
    outputDate = inputDate;
}
return outputDate;
  }
 }
```

and this is a my base adapter code

```
public class HollAdapters extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

private final ArrayList<CinemaInfoModel> hollitems1;

public HollAdapters(Context context, ArrayList<CinemaInfoModel> hollitems) {
    mContext = context;

    this.hollitems1 = hollitems;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return hollitems1.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

@SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cinema_holl_adapter,
                parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
        viewHolder.start_time = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.adapter_day);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } 
    viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();

    CinemaInfoModel objectItem = hollitems1.get(position);
    if (objectItem != null) {




            String starttimes = objectItem.getStartTimePeriod().get(
                    position);


            viewHolder.start_time.setText(starttimes);
            Log.e("adapter start time", starttimes);



    }

    return convertView;

}

static class ViewHolderItem {
    private TextView start_time;

 }
}
```

[this is a my logcat message's screenshot](http://i.share.pho.to/1559d1c4_o.png) (i 'm new user and i can't post image)

i have not idea what is a wrong in my code... if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: Could please be more specific? What results You want to have? what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: @ Opiatefuchs please see my picture.in red line is baseadapter getStartTimePeriod message and in green line as  MoviesRolls class 's setStartTimePeriod message and there both are different.i want to recive same as MoviesRolls class 's setStartTimePeriod message

Comment: Please do not duplicate your questions, this identical to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421010/android-base-adapter-does-not-adapter-all-rows/27421265#27421265)

Comment: @Kelevandos sorry i 'm new user and .... help me if you can sir

Answer (score 0):

Try this , Please change you code like this. If convertView is null means it will inflate layout, Else it will reuse the view. Let me know if you need any clarification

```
  if (convertView == null) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cinema_holl_adapter,
            parent, false);

    viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
    viewHolder.start_time = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.adapter_day);

    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

}else{
viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
}
/*** Do your stuff here***/
```

Comment: Else block is not required here. Actually, it is not desirable at all. The tag should at all times be retrieved from the view.

Comment: Its required please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921462/listview-reusing-views-when-i-dont-want-it-to

Comment: I can tell you from experience it is not. And all this `else{` block does is make the code more complex.

Comment: http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/ clearly explained this blog

Comment: I know the pattern. All I am referring to here is the face that the `else{` block is redundant and does not do anything at all, only darkens the code.

Comment: @Kelevandos nothing changed

Comment: @baggio Thank you for confirming this :-) Please now answer my question :-)

Comment: I had faced same issue last year. I used above code its working fine for me.